# What kind of results can I expect with a Profoto Zoom Reflector?

Tags: flash, off-camera-flash, light, lighting-modifiers, profoto

I am trying to find sample photos that are made with the **"Profoto Zoom Reflector 2"**. I looked the reflector up in YouTube videos and a Google image search, and I still don't get what kind of light quality you can make with it. If you have more information about this light modifier please share so I get a visual idea of what kind of lighting this modifier is made for.

Comment: what are you looking photograph? these are very good for close crop work i.E, a models head and shoulders with a prop or two. with hard light fall off to the sides to create drama. good for dramatic fashion photoshoots

Comment: Thanks @AbdulNQuraishi  yes,my friend is a fashion design student and wanted to help her with photos. But she also wants "Full Body" shots, do I have to switch to an Octa 2" I have if I want the Full Body?
Currently I have these, would be awesome if you give me guiadance on mostly to go with which one for more close up shoot of face and shoulders and which one for full body shots, I have these from Profoto:
Wide zoom reflector, with grid
Zoom Reflector 2, with grid
Beauty dish, white, w/ grid
Octa 2" softbox w/ grid
Snoot with grid
Deep Umbrealls, medium size, Black, Silver, Translucent

Comment: the best way to get a more precise answer to the challenges you face would be to post a few individual questions with examples of the types of shots you are looking to achieve. include what you have. to me, you seem to have enough to cover pretty much everything. great fashions shots can be captured with just 3 speed lights and some tracing paper and made to look as if they were done in a massive studio with a large budget. Post the questions with images and lets take it form there.

Answer (score 1):

The Zoom Reflector will typically give a hard light (well-defined transitions from light to shadow), as you'll usually have the strobe relatively far from the subject. The Zoom Reflector will focus the light in the direction it's pointing, as opposed to a bare bulb or the built-in reflector on the B1, B2, D2, etc.